# How To Know Udemy Course Creation Date

Tags: udemy

**Hi**
I Search for very long time about getting udemy course creation date 
but nothing

Why Udemy Hide That Date ? and only show update date !!

If Not How Can I Get it ?

Comment: Not possible anymore. A workaround for software development related courses is to lookup the version history of the packages the instructor is using which can sometimes be seen when he instructs you to download certain software in the setup phase of the course. The information in the book is from around the time those versions were released.

Comment: I'm not sure why Udemy hid the creation date of the courses, and I don't know any place on the UI that this specific piece of data is displayed. Yet you can call their API directly and request for that. Below I listed a few API calls that spit out the creation date in a JSON format:  

`https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/COURSE_ID/?fields[course]=title,url,created` .

For `COURSE_ID`: Go to the course page, right-click on the page and select `View page source` (Ctrl+U). Then look (Ctrl+F) for the `data-clp-course-id` attribute which contains the ID.

Comment: Try this tool: https://www.infognu.com/udemy-course-date-finder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't able to obtain this data from within the course. You can only obtain it from the page that displays the courses taught by the author. This only works on the website version and not on the Android and iOS app.

**STEP 1**: View the detail page of the course
[image: Course info]

**STEP 2**: Scroll down until you see the author(s). Click on any of them.
[image: Click on any of the author(s)]

**STEP 3**: Scroll down a little to view the *courses taught by the author*.
[image: Courses by author]

**STEP 4**: Locate the course of which you want to know the creation date. It might be on a different page, use the pager if needed. DO NOT click on the course once you found it. Instead, hover your mouse cursor over it. A small blade would pop up. Look for `Published` at the top of the blade. That would be your Creation Date.
[image: Course pop up blade]

Comment: Not possible anymore.

Comment: Outdated answer

Comment: Try this free tool: https://www.infognu.com/udemy-course-date-finder

Comment: @MuhammadNabeel worked

Answer (score 3):

The only luck we have now is based on the reviews. We need to scroll through all the reviews and check the oldest review post date. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE as of FEB 4 2020
It's not possible to see the published date anymore. The published date is hidden.  Udemy removed it all together.