# How to find Udemy course creation date

Tags: udemy

Any idea how to find the creation date of an Udemy course?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Self-answers are fine, but you need to put the solution where it belongs: in an *answer*, not in the question. Please see [this Help Center article](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Yes, try this tool: https://infognu.com/udemy-course-creation-date-finder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I don't have enough 'points' to comment on the other question on this topic [How To Know Udemy Course Creation Date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135660/how-to-know-udemy-course-creation-date?rq=1), I leave the NEW solution here.

1. Go to the course you want to find the date for, and hit Right Click => Inspect (in Chrome)
2. On the `body` tag look for `data-clp-course-id="xxxxxx"` and copy the ID value
3. Now paste the ID in this URL (instead of x-s) https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/xxxxxx/?fields[course]=created and navigate on it.

That's it guys!

Comment: This works. Thanks bro. Hopefully udemy team will not remove this tag and id in the future.

Comment: https://infognu.com/udemy-course-creation-date-finder This tool exactly does what this answer mentioned. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this issue, I created a **Google Chrome extension that adds the creation date** inside the courses pages.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/udemy-creation-date/poadjkobojgpphiifndghonmofhldhmn?fbclid=IwAR2bhSFfcBjtBSitOl2EXOASCcrDFrYdyH9O8iSNOYMckNcbJn4nQ3nQYB0

[image: comparisson]

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either Udemy or the instructor are doing what they can to keep that information undetectable. I purchased a course on how to use Excel for data analysis like an expert. The title failed to mention that the course was about the "brand new" Excel 2013, despite the course overview stating that it was recently updated. Using the above method and extension indicate that the course was "created" in April 2020, but we can assume it has been recycled. I'd be inclined to say that the instructor had created the course elsewhere and made it available on Udemy within the year. But the fact that Udemy has deliberately modified their site to prevent the original publication date from appearing anywhere suggests they have a hand in it. My suggestion is to keep your expectations low on Udemy courses, especially ones offered at a discount price.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool: https://infognu.com/udemy-course-creation-date-finder

[image: udemy-course-date-finder]

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by 'newest' when you are looking for a course to download.

Hope that is helpful